# Basic C Questions. fprintf and fgets failures

Tags: c

I've got some basic c questions that are driving me insane. Let me post my code, and I'll tell you about what's going wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int GetLine();


int main() {
char* sourceFile;
char* destinationFile;
int error, bytesRead;
char* sourceFD;
char* destinationFD;
char buffer[100];

error = GetLine("Please enter a source file name: \n", sourceFile, 100);
if (error == 1) {
    printf("A source file was not inputted.\n");
    return 0;
}
else if (error == 2) {
    printf("Source file is too long.\n");
    return 0;
}

error = GetLine("Please enter a destination file name: \n", destinationFile, 100);
if (error == 1) {
    printf("A destination file was not inputted.\n");
    return 0;
}
else if (error == 2) {
    printf("Destination file is too long.\n");
    return 0;
}
}

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2
static int GetLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, unsigned int sz) {
int ch, extra;

// Get line with buffer overrun protection.
if (prmpt != NULL) {
    printf("%s", prmpt);
    fflush(stdout);
}
}

if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "fgets returned NULL");
    return NO_INPUT;
}

printf("logging input: %s", buff);

// If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
// to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
    extra = 0;
    while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
        extra = 1;
    return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
}

// Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
return OK;
}
```

The errors are occurring in the the GetLine function, which was largely provided by another StackOverflow post. Here are my issues.

1. No matter what I do, I cannot get debug print statements to work properly. basic printf will often fail. Calling fflush(stdout) immediately after does not help, nor does setbuf(stdout, NULL). Right now I am trying fprintf(stderr), also to no avail. The LOC that continually fails (regardless of the method I try) is fprintf(stderr, "fgets returned NULL"). Note that the application still gives me the error that "A source file was not inputted." It doesn't matter if I target stdout or stderr.
2. fgets is returning NULL every time. I have no idea why. No, the input I'm providing is not large.

EDIT: I just noticed the missing brackets on that if statement (the fgets one). let me see what that fixes.

Comment: Hint: when you call `GetLine("Please enter a source file name: \n", sourceFile, 100);`, what value does `sourceFile` have? (the pointer itself)

Comment: And, *if your question is answered, don't fix the code in the question* because then it looks like you never had that problem. If you've accepted an answer, and your code has other unrelated problems, post another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "fgets returned NULL");
    return NO_INPUT;
```

Here `return NO_INPUT;` is always executed no matter what `fgets()` returns. Use `{}` to enclose the two statements.

Comment: hahah I just saw that as well. Thank you. That explains both errors perfectly

Comment: That's what I get for programming in Python so much. This looks normal

Comment: Alright, one more error now. The second time we call GetLine, the fgets still fails with a bus error. It doesn't return NULL. It just crashes the program. ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (prmpt != NULL) {
    printf("%s", prmpt);
    fflush(stdout);
}
}
```

Here you are closing GetLine but your code continues